# How to clear cache of Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to know what is the standard way to clear the cache of Eclipse Indigo?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'cache'?

Comment: @home "The little bits of information that Eclipse randomly stores and corrupts." (You know, why "clean" and "delete project/workspace" solutions are so popular .. it's because they sometimes actually restore broken "cache" information. I miss Visual Studio.)

Answer (score 36):

you can use -clean parameter while starting eclipse like

C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin" -clean

Comment: @SagarNikam: go to your eclipse home folder and run ./eclipse -clean

Answer (score 16):

If you are asking about cache where eclipse stores your project and workspace information right click on your project(s) and choose refresh. Then go to project in the menu on top of the window and click "clean".

This typically does what you need.

If it does not try to remove project from the workspace (just press "delete" on the project and then say that you DO NOT want to remove the sources). Then open project again.

If this does not work too, do the same with the workspace. If this still does not work, perform fresh checkout of your project from source control and create new workspace.

Well, this should work.

Comment: +1 for checkout and create new workspace. That finally worked after hours of being unable to start tomcat from eclipse.

Answer (score 7):

Instructions

1. Open Eclipse and navigate to the `Window` > `Preferences`.
2. Scroll down the left-hand panel in the Preferences window and click
   the `Remote Systems` drop-down root menu. Select `File Cache`.
3. Click the `Clear Cached Files` button in the File Cache window. Note
   that this will automatically close any open remote files on your
   computer.
4. Press `Apply` and `OK` to save your changes and exit out of the
   Preferences window.

Comment: Would down-vote if I could, very specific to the version of Eclipse and misleading for others.

Comment: works for most of the versions,also we expect people not to use 100 years old eclipse.. :)
which version did you try?

Comment: MyEclipse Enterprise Workbench

Version: 2014
Build id: 12.0.0-20131202

No option "Remote Systems"

Comment: @Xogle: please check the question again, the user asks for a specified version(Eclipse Indigio).
Please check once before defaming an answer...!
(though i will find a solution for urs as well)

Comment: @Xogle you could use the search from Preferences for "File cache" and stop complaining about not seeing the exact steps to get there!

Answer (score 5):

You can always create a new Eclipse workspace. The `Eclipse.exe -clean` option is ***not sufficient*** *in some cases*, for example, if the local history becomes a problem.

**Edit:**

Eclipse is mostly a collection of third party plugins. And each of those plugins can add some extra useful, useless or problematic information to the central Eclipse workspace meta-data folder.

The problem is that not every plugin participates during the user-issued cleanup routine. Therefore, I'd say that it is a problem in the system design of Eclipse, that it allows plugins to misbehave like this.

And therefore, I'd recommend to make yourself comfortable with the idea of using multiple workspaces and linking-in external project entities into each workspace. Because, this is the only workaround for the given system design, to handle faulty plugins that spam your workspace.

Answer (score 3):

Clear improperly cached compile errors.
All Projects Locations in Eclipse

`workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\<project>\`

Comment: What did you mean by "Clear improperly cached compile errors." ? I removed everything in `workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\<project>\` and now, I get an error (backup the data before doing it). I was forced to delete the project and import it again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find the answer you want in these two posts. They are mentioning Flash Builder, but essentially, the talk is about its Eclipse base.

Clear improperly cached compile errors in FlexBuilder:
http://blog.aherrman.com/2010/05/clear-improperly-cached-compile-errors.html

How to fix Flash Builder broken workspace:
http://va.lent.in/how-to-fix-flash-builder-broken-workspace/

Answer (score 0):

Goto this directory

> /workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches/

Remove the debug file ".launch" you don't need.

Answer (score -13):

It's very simple. Right click inside the internal browser and click "refresh".

Comment: this action does not clears cache of eclipse workspace.