# not showing Android sdk And AVD manager in eclipse....why?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using Windows 7 and Eclipse luna. I installed all packages successfully and I could run avd on the command line, but Eclipse was not showing the AVD Manager window and my android project. Why?

Comment: answer: now you must have figured it out on your eclipse menu bar go to

window
customize perspective
command group availability tab
on the check box android SDK and AVD manager check it
click on ok
That should work.

Comment: did you added sdk manager path? eclipse>windows>preferences>android>sdk location

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting your computer unit, since you installed a new program, maybe Eclipse isn't yet recognizing the Android SDK and AVD Manager. Let me know if this helped at all.

Comment: Thank you @lea for responce i got answer: now you must have figured it out on your eclipse menu bar go to window customize perspective command group availability tab on the check box android SDK and AVD manager check it click on ok .

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible I suggest you first uninstall eclipse completely from your system  now fallow thes steps:

1) install jdk1.7

2)set path of it in environment option of my computer property

3)type-> javac on command line

4)now install eclipse Zono in your system

5)during presses you create workspace
6)now you see eclipse home page
7) Select windows option from menu
8)choose prefrence option than choose android option
9)select path of your android sdk  .press ok.
10) select windows->select vertuial device manager ->create AVD ->start

Answer (score 0):

If u have configured the SDK correctly, try clearing eclipse cache.

Following link may be helpful.

[How to clear cache of Eclipse Indigo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250041/how-to-clear-cache-of-eclipse-indigo)