# How to clean cache in Eclipse Neon v 4.6.0?

Tags: eclipse, selenium

How to clean cache in Eclipse Neon v 4.6.0?
I have an automation test with selenium. The test is passed bug there sometimes the the test is failed and it looks like it is stuck. I want to clean the cache.

Comment: om menu bar click  project > clean

Answer (score 0):

The Question doesn't mentions about which `cache` you are trying to clean up.

As you mentioned `cache in Eclipse Neon v 4.6.0?` to do that you have to execute the following steps:

1. On Eclipse, Click on `Project` -> `Build Automatically` (keep the option selected)
2. Again, on Eclipse, Click on **`Project`** -> **`Clean`**, click **`Clean all projects`** & click **`OK`**

Incase you are trying to clean the `Browser cache`, you don't need to worry for that as, whenever you do:

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
```

A new **`Mozilla Profile`** is created on the fly which doesn't have anything stored in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this by referencing this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250041/how-to-clear-cache-of-eclipse-indigo)

```
 C:\eclipse\eclipse.exe -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin" -clean
```