# Control Click from .feature file to Step Definition is not working

Tags: cucumber

I am using Cucumber with Java on Eclipse IDE.
Trying to navigate from .feature file to Step definition, however when I hit enter button and hover mouse to the Given, then or When it is not turning in to hyperlink and after click as well not going anywhere.

Comment: Does navigating to a step definition work in your IDE if you load a different project? I have a similar problem in Visual Studio as well. Deleting temp files generated by your IDE might solve the problem, since I imagine Eclipse generates a cache of step definition mappings. Maybe [How to clear cache of Eclipse Indigo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9250041/3092298) can give you some ideas.

Comment: In your Runner class, define where feature file exists and where its step definition files exists.

Comment: Are you using Cucumber 5? There are opened issues about this:
  [1]: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse/issues/372
  [2]: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse/issues/368

Answer (score 11):

Install **Cucumber Eclipse Plugin** from **Eclipse Marketplace**;
Once the plugin is installed, `Create a feature file`;
Right Click on Project -> Configure -> Convert to Cucumber project;
Now try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> on any step from feature file.

Answer (score 5):

Install " Cucumber Eclipse Plugin " From Eclipse Marketplace once the plugin is installed
Create a feature file .

**Right Click on Project -> Configure -> Convert to Cucumber project**

once its Converted all steps within feature file will redirect to step-definition

[Path to Convert Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsoNQ.png)

Answer (score 2):

- Uninstall Cucumber from marketplace and restart the eclipse
- Then just search for keyword "Cucumber" in the marketplace, install it and restart  Eclipse.
- Now from project tree open your feature file with "Cucumber Editor".
- Control + Click and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Cucumber 5? There are opened issues about this:

1. [cucumber-eclipse plugin does not support Cucumber 5](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse/issues/372)
2. [.feature
   doesn't work with import from io.cucumber but work with
   cucumber.api](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-eclipse/issues/368)

Comment: This should probably be a comment. It doesn't really answer the question since you are unsure about what OP uses. You have 50 rep, post is as a comment instead, so that you  will not get downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Following 3 steps are quite handy while configuring any Cucumber project from new/existing in Eclipse:

1. Install these 2 Plugins from Eclipse Marketplace - Cucumber Eclipse & Natural
2. Right-click on project and select **Configure -> Convert to Cucumber Project...**
3. Install pending Eclipse updates, if any.

This will solve the original problem of control click (navigation to step definition file from feature file) in Eclipse as well.